# How do you say "senior agent" in spanish?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

As in more "experienced" customer service agent

Comment: `Agente lider` could be

Comment: Can you provide some more context, please? A simple term like this is almost never possible to translate directly without a lot of context.

Answer (score 3):

The term 'senior agent' in the meaning of 'seasoned agent', which is what you seem to want, is not directly translatable into spanish.

Spain (this is old enough that it is also related to other spanish-speaking countries) has a learning system at work that makes people start as apprentices (*Aprendiz*) and then jump to fully featured workers as second-class handworkers (*Oficial de segunda*). These can, with experience, become first-class handworkers (*Oficial de primera*) with the same workload and kind of work. It just happens that they get more salary, and also that **in the absence of a team leader** they become the team's head.

Problem is that *Oficial de primera* is mainly used in handworking professions (builder, labourer, carpenter) but not in places where we would use 'agent' in English.

On the wild, I would use *experimentado* (seasoned) or *superior*.

Comment: You can also use `experto` that describes much more the experience and expertise.

Answer (score 2):

In Spain we take some English terms and don't traslate them, maybe Senior agent just mean "Agente senior" in Spanish.

For example, in some companies, the ranges are "Programador junior" or "Programador senior".

Comment: Agree with you and the same happens in Mexico, my job title is "Programador Senior", senior pronounced as "sinior".

Comment: It is amusing or depressing or, depending on your point of view, maybe a bit of both to note that "junior" and "senior" are really Latin words, used in these contexts by people who certainly have no idea of their etymology.

Comment: @MichaelWolf, Which part of this was amusing and depressing? The Latin word for "junior" is "juvenis". Junior is the word used in English. So isn't he correct in saying that it is a word borrowed from English? Despite the fact that it has a history that is traced back to Latin?

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use would be "Gerente" or "Supervisor" which falls into the the category of Senior Agent/ Supervisor

Answer (score 1):

There may be regional differences, but at least in the South American job market it is common to directly use the terms *senior*, *semi senior*, *junior* for office job titles.

So, in your example you could say *Ejecutivo senior de atención al cliente*, or *Ejecutivo de atención al cliente senior*.